# how to return only the names of the people from an array born between certain ages with a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

This is the code I'm currently working with. For an example "findCodersBetween(coders, 1960, 1986)" would return "[{name: 'Alice', born: 1990}, {name: 'Susan', born: 1960}, {name: 'Charlotte', born: 1986}]". But what I want is for the function to only output the names "['Alice', 'Susan', 'Charlotte']". I think the answer is simple I just can't figure it out.

```js
const allCoders = [
  {name: 'Ada', born: 1816},
  {name: 'Alice', born: 1990},
  {name: 'Susan', born: 1960},
  {name: 'Eileen', born: 1936},
  {name: 'Zoe', born: 1995},
  {name: 'Charlotte', born: 1986},
]

const findCodersBetween = (coders, startYear, endYear) => {
  return coders.filter((coder) => coder.born >= startYear && coder.born <= endYear);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` and return only the `name`: `.map(coder => coder.name)`

```js
const allCoders = [
  {name: 'Ada', born: 1816},
  {name: 'Alice', born: 1990},
  {name: 'Susan', born: 1960},
  {name: 'Eileen', born: 1936},
  {name: 'Zoe', born: 1995},
  {name: 'Charlotte', born: 1986},
]

const findCodersBetween = (coders, startYear, endYear) => {
  return coders.filter((coder) => coder.born >= startYear && coder.born <= endYear).map(coder => coder.name);
};

console.log(findCodersBetween(allCoders, 1960, 1986))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `filter` returns the *objects* that match the condition (note that "Alice" wouldn't be returned in your example as `1990` is greater than `1986`) you need to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the returned array of objects and, for each coder, return just the name from the object.

```js
const allCoders = [
  {name: 'Ada', born: 1816},
  {name: 'Alice', born: 1990},
  {name: 'Susan', born: 1960},
  {name: 'Eileen', born: 1936},
  {name: 'Zoe', born: 1995},
  {name: 'Charlotte', born: 1986},
]

const findCodersBetween = (coders, startYear, endYear) => {
  return coders.filter(coder => {
    return coder.born >= startYear && coder.born <= endYear;
  }).map(coder => coder.name);
}

console.log(findCodersBetween(allCoders, 1960, 1986));
```